# JSON + Jinja validator tool

Tags: json, jinja2, jsonlint

I have a JSON templates with Jinja template code. JSON Lint can validate JSON but borks on Jinja characters.

Is there a tool (editor add-on, online, or CLI) that validates JSON and Jinja?

Or can one suggest how to do this with JSONLint and recommend a good Jinja validator?